# How to deploy wordpress to live server

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment, server, web-deployment

I have server credentials and want to deploy me wordpress site.
Please give me any solution how to access a server from my window as i have credentials:
1- Host
2- login/username
3- Password
4- allow IP

Allow IP is a single ip address like this "10.0.1.1/8"
I had tried to connect using filezilla but there is no option of Ip-address.
Anyone who faced this issue please guide me.

Comment: you have to connect with the hostname through filezilla, like [this](https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/basic-usage-instructions/connecting-to-a-server/)

Comment: hostname not provided by client

Comment: what about your first credential? `1- Host`

Comment: that is something like this "10.1.200.162"

Comment: that is an [private network address](https://www.avast.com/c-ip-address-public-vs-private); in order to access the server, you are going to need a public address of the server, or to be in the same network of the host (if the server is on-promise)